# Why when you click an app in the Google Chrome, the app icon become larger not smaller?

Tags: user-behavior, google, click

When you click something you expect the size of that object or thing become smaller. But in Google Chrome when you click on an app, the icon of that app becomes larger.
I'd like to know why Google chrome behaves like this?

[image]

Comment: "when you click something you expect the size of that object or thing become smaller" = what are you basing that on?

Comment: in the real world you expect when you push or press something, it become smaller or sunk.

Comment: Ah, well, if it were a 3D button, I guess I'd agree. Can you post an image as an example for those of us that don't use apps in chrome?

Comment: i can't post image, sorry... I've not enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think partly what Google chrome is trying to suggest is that you are picking up the object.

1. If you click and hold the icon you can then drag it around
2. but if you pick it up and let it go then it will take you to the app.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes bigger because they chose to **emphasise what you are selecting** over trying to match some sense of real world perspective.

I agree with their choices, as it's more important that you emphasise what has been selected than matching what would happen in the real world to a similar object.  Modelling digital interactions on real world objects is not always the best choice.

Comment: as you know, in graphic design contrast or opposition is a way to show emphasis.
i can't be agree with you. They can reach their goal by smalling icons!

Comment: @ehsania think of touch devices for a moment. If your finger is on the icon, making it smaller will offer little visible contrast.  Making it bigger however is something that you may notice.